# how to do not is in with blank values in pandas

Tags: pandas

So I have a dataframe with itemlist and a list of inventory that contains product_id(as a result of a different function). My aim here is to get the differences back from itemlist to that of inventory based on product id. However sometimes when the inventory list is empty, the item returns all itemlist.  Shouldn't the items return empty when nothing is in the inventory?
Isn't the logic that it is not in a blank, so it returns nothing? can someone explain this?

itemlist table

| product_id | dec |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | desc a |
| 2 | desc b |
| 3 | desc c |

inventory =[]

when inventory = 1 , items return is 2,3.

but when inventory is [] it returns 1,2,3

```
items = itemlist[~itemlist['product_id'].isin(inventory)]['product_id'].values.tolist()
```

Comment: could you include a sample?

Comment: sample added already, please do check

Comment: if `items` is the complement of `inventory`, isn't it logical that if `inventory` is empty, it should be equal to the set of `product_ids`?

Comment: hm.. ok that makes senses i guess, so I have to handle if it's empty. ok got it.